# Unable to retrieve the value of the method as a variable in components Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7

Laravel 7 comes with components and with them it has a feature that allows us to retrieve the value of the method as a variable in our view.

It is supposed to work like this and print 'This is list' whenever component is called but its giving me error

> Undefined variable: list (View: /home/invito/Documents/Laravel/reparet/resources/views/components/passdata.blade.php)

```php
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Passdata extends Component
{
    public $title;
    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($title)
    {
        $this->title = $title;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        return view('components.passdata');
    }

    public function list()
    {
        return 'This is list';
    }
}
```

//View

```
<div>

   {{$list}}
</div>
```

Comment: Did you register the component? If so, how? And how are you trying to use it?